# Mobile Device Testing

Tags: browser-automation, mobile

We are currently testing a new website on device. However I believe we could test by operating system version and Prominent browser instead. Has anyone else tried this approach rather than testing on every device?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to get from the community here? Can you give more details?

Answer (score 1):

I guess to minimize risks, but limit mobile testing to a limited number of devices.

I would test on something like:

- Each different Mobile OS version still in use significantly
- Latest major browser versions on those OS's
- Most used resolutions of Mobile devices

Still I would wonder how much more confidence I would get when testing with more devices. Maybe a shortlist would be enough.

I would create a shortlist based on *last 3 months* data from http://gs.statcounter.com/

- Screen resolution
- Browser version
- Operating system

Answer (score 0):

We tried to base our Android tests on marketing surveys, the results were mixed.
To begin with a marketing name like 'Nokia 6210' is not good enough, you need a specific model ID since hardware and software have significant variations.

Then we found, as expected, that the market is highly segregated- each model has a really small percentage of market share, and it's far from being statistically significant to choose between a 1.12% (of market share) device and 1.43%.

But at the end you don't have another, better, choice. There are hundreds of sub models, sub OS and browser versions putting a huge price tag on testing, even if you use this or that virtual, remote test services

Answer (score 0):

Testing for all devices is difficult thing. But you can test your app by checking different OS version-wise.
If you looking to test on different devices you use third party service provider for cloud device.
Try for [Testdroid/Bitbar](http://bitbar.com/testing/try-for-free/), here you can get free devices for Manual Testing too.